# Sync Google Sheets with Web Page HTML

Tags: google-apps-script, synchronization

What is the easiest way I can sync a sync a google sheet with a web page form (see attached picture)?  Ideally an example code or tutorial.

Here is what I want: I want users to access my web page so they can select their name from a drop-down menu and put it next to the item they wish.  Then once they click submit, each person's name value will be transferred from the webpage and then recorded into the corresponding cell inside the google spreadsheet.  Then when the next user comes to the site, the fields will auto-populate from the google sheet so he will see who has picked what and what choices are left.

Ideally I would just send the users directly to the google sheet to make their selections, however, they can't edit it on a mobile phone without d/l the app and a bunch of other bogus roadblocks.  Google Forms also does not work for this for several reasons.

Some things to keep in mind:
- the spreadsheet is totally public and editable.  So I'm hoping to avoid the need to set up an API
- no security or login necessary for the users (I am not worried about if someone changes someone else's name)

I have spent weeks trying to find how to do this but I'm just a construction worker I don't know technology
[SYNCING HTML FORM WITH GOOGLE SHEET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oE8jo.png)

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is what you want, if you can use the web page as Web Apps of Google, I think that it can achieve what you want using Google Apps Script, and you can get and put the values of Spreadsheet. In this case, the Spreadsheet is not required to be published. The document of Web Apps is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

Comment: BRILLIANT!!!  OMG BRILLIANT!!! You are correct, this is PERFECT!!  5-star for you!  thank you

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was solved.

Answer (score 1):

From Tanaike,

> If you can use the web page as Web Apps of Google, I think that it can achieve what
>   you want using Google Apps Script, and you can get and put the values
>   of Spreadsheet. In this case, the Spreadsheet is not required to be
>   published. The document of Web Apps is [can be found in comments].

– Tanaike 10/19/2018